# Correctly reorganising JSON to JS array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a JSON string that is similar to below:

```
[
    {"id":"112233","region":"UK","city":"London","name":"Company 1"},
    {"id":"112244","region":"UK","city":"London","name":"Company 2"},
    {"id":"112255","region":"UK","city":"Manchester","name":"Company 3"},
    {"id":"112266","region":"UK","city":"Manchester","name":"Company 4"}
]
```

I am trying to rebuild this into a JS array like this:

```
[
    { 
        ["London"]: [
                    ["112233"] : [{"id":"112233","region":"UK","city":"London","name":"Company 1"}],
                    ["11224"] : [{"id":"112244","region":"UK","city":"London","name":"Company 2"}],
                ],
        ["Manchester"]: [
                    ["112255"] : [{"id":"112255","region":"UK","city":"Manchester","name":"Company 3"}],
                    ["112266"] : [{"id":"112266","region":"UK","city":"Manchester","name":"Company 4"}]
                ]
    }
]
```

Here is the code I am using to do this:

```
var company = [];
var companies = [];
var cities = [];

// generate citites
for (var i = 0; i < dump.length; i++)
{
    // check if city exits
    if(!cities.includes(dump[i].city.trim())) {
        cities[dump[i].city.trim()] = companies;
    }
}

// add companies
for (var i = 0; i < dump.length; i++)
{
    company['company_name'] = dump[i].company_name;
    company['region'] = dump[i].region;
    cities[dump[i].city][dump[i].id] = company;
}
console.log(cities);
```

Now I get an error stating `Cannot set property '112233' of undefined TypeError: Cannot set property '112233' of undefined`.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It would be better to make :
 ["London"] ... An object instead of array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formatting of your desired results is a little strange because you are using `[]` for what looks like objects with keys. I'm assuming that's a typos and that you really want an object.

Here's a quick easy way to do that with `reduce()`:

```js
let dump = [
    {"id":"112233","region":"UK","city":"London","name":"Company 1"},
    {"id":"112244","region":"UK","city":"London","name":"Company 2"},
    {"id":"112255","region":"UK","city":"Manchester","name":"Company 3"},
    {"id":"112266","region":"UK","city":"Manchester","name":"Company 4"}
]

let obj = dump.reduce((obj, item) => {
    let city = obj[item.city] || (obj[item.city] = {}) // add city obj to object if not there.
    city[item.id] = item                               // add item.id to city obj
    return obj
}, {})
console.log(obj)
```

EDIT:

The way [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) works is to start with a value that is passed in the second parameter, here that's an empty object `{}` that is called `obj` in the callback, and then iterate through the array (`dump`). With each iteration we look and see if this `obj` has a property with the name of the current item in the iteration. If not add it and assign a new object `{}`. Then with that object in hand, add a property corresponding to `item.id` and adding the whole `item` to it.

You could write the entire thing as a for loop, but `reduce` is pretty succinct — it just takes a while to get used to it.

Comment: Thanks for your response Mark, could you add a little explanation into what the function does here... it works but I don't know how lol

Comment: @Imran -- see edit. reduce() takes a little while to get used to, but it's very useful once you've got it.